# How do you use markers in vi?

Tags: c++, c, vim

I just discovered the existence of markers in vi. How do you use it, what do you know about them? are they useful, say for a C++ developer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use them all the time for:

- commenting out blocks of code,
- copying and moving blocks of code,
- yanking and deleting blocks of code into named buffers, and
- **Edit:** substituting in a block of test.

Commenting out:

- go to the first line of the code you want to comment out,
- mark it, e.g. enter `ma`
- go to the end of the block
- enter `:'a,.s/^/#` (or whatever comment character you need)

Copying and moving:

- mark first line as above,
- go to bottom of block you want to copy/move
- enter your second different marker, e.g. `mb`
- go to where you want to copy the block and enter `:'a,'bco .`  or `:'a,'bmo .` to copy or move resp.

Yanking to a named buffer:

- mark first line as above,
- go to bottom of block you want to yank
- enter `:'a,.ya a` will yank the block into buffer a or `:'a,.ya A` will append the block onto the current contents of buffer a

**Edit:** Substituting in a block of text:

- mark first line as above,
- go to the bottom of the block you want to substitute in
- enter `:'a,.s/search_string/replace_string/[gc]` which will subtitute in your text block. Adding 'g' or 'c' after the last slash will invoke the usual global and confirm functionality.

**Edit:** Forgot to say, remember that `'a` (apostrophe a) refers to the line containing the marker and `` `a `` (backtick a) refers to the character on the line that you marked.

So `` `ad`b `` (bactic-a-d-backtic-b) is a useful little snippet to delete the text in a line from the char marked with 'a' up to the char **before** the char marked with b.

By the way, in Vim, entering `:reg` will give you the contents of all your registers incl. your delete registers.

Answer (score 3):

I use them when I need to jump around in a large file.  For example, if I'm working on two interrelated functions, one which is defined near the top of the file and one which is defined near the bottom, I can set markers to quickly jump back and forth between the two locations.

If I'm declaring a class or working with a declaration I'm not familiar with, it's often helpful to mark the spot where things are first explained so that I can jump back for a quick reference.

Markers are useful in general, but I don't think they're any more (or less) useful just becuase you're developing in C++.

These are only some ideas -- I'm sure there will be many other good ones out there.

Comment: If the marker is set using `ma`, then you can jump back using `'a`.

Answer (score 2):

The most common use is for copy-paste or deleting large blocks.
Move to the first line of the block, type `mx`
Move to the last line of the block, type `y'x` to copy the whole block (to the clipboard), or `d'x` to delete (cut) it. In either case, `p` or `P` can be used to paste it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Markers act as a good way to get back to the beginning of a line or an exact location in a line.

I'll typically use them when I want to extract or copy a portion of code.  Consider the following:

```
int tmp = 0;
while (tmp < 10)
{
    doIt(tmp); /* cursor before d */
    /* ... */
    finishIt(tmp);
    tmp++
}
```

If I want to extract from `doIt(tmp)` to `finishIt(tmp)`, I'd then set a marker at the cursor (`ma` for example), navigate to finishIt, and then delete to mark a with `d'a`.

Comment: I find it much easier to just use visual selection then press d, or what the command may be.  I use this technique most often to do a search and replace of a selection of text.